# Combine column from multiple rows into one row in SQLITE

Tags: query, join, sqlite

I have a sqlite-database with the schema

```
Articles
 Id
 Name

Tags
 Id
 Name

ArticlesTags
 Id
 ArticleId
 TagId
```

I´m trying to query for Articles.Name and a LIST of tags. Basically what I would want is:

```
Name1, (tag1,tag2,tag3)
Name2, (tag3,tag2)
```

Is this possible?
I´m lacking the language to explain what I actually want to do, what is it called?

I found [Combine column from multiple rows into single row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17921/combine-column-from-multiple-rows-into-single-row) but it seems limited to SQLServer and the usage of builtin xml-features of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) function:

```
SELECT a.Name               AS ArticleName
     , GROUP_CONCAT(t.Name) AS TagList
FROM Articles AS a
  LEFT JOIN ArticlesTags AS at
    ON at.ArticleId = a.Id
  LEFT JOIN Tags AS t
    ON t.Id = at.TagId
GROUP BY a.Id, a.Name ;
```